# Phing cannot write logs on OS X with MAMP PHP for CLI - how do I fix its permissions?

Tags: php, mamp, osx-mavericks, phing

**What I did:**

After executing $ ./vendor/bin/phing - I get the error below

The Phing ERROR:

> [phing] FileSystem::chown() FAILED. Cannot chown /Users/nomad/Projects/BuildingWithPhing/logs/application.log. User www-data.

**What I expect:**

I expect Phing to be able to write to its own log file

**The setup**

I installed Phing with Composer

```
"require": {
    "phing/phing": "2.5.0"
}
```

I set up my environment to use MAMP PHP version 5.5.3 for php cli

I am using macintosh OS X Mavericks

**Question:**
How do I fix Phing permissions?
Should I make a www-data member have root permission, and if so how?

**Update 1**

I set up the build target below (suggested by gafreax), but it still fails with:

> [phing] FileSystem::chown() FAILED. Cannot chown /Users/nomad/Projects/BuildingWithPhing/logs/application.log. User www-data.

```
<target name="permissions">
    <echo msg="Set up permissions..." />

    <exec command="cd ../" dir="${project.basedir}"/>
    <exec command="chown -vR developer:www-data ./" />
    <exec command="find -type d -exec chmod 775 {} +" />
    <exec command="find -type f -exec chmod 664 {} +" />

</target>
```

**Update 2**

I tried editing the sudoers file (suggested by gafreax), but it keeps giving syntax errors, and its a mission to repair.

In case you broke your sudoers file - Replace it with a backup and run "Repair Permissions" in "Disk Utilities". That gets you back on track.

So I am still stuck.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty solution: with your user do

```
chgrp -R www-data /Users/nomad/Projects/BuildingWithPhing/logs
chmod g+rw /Users/nomad/Projects/BuildingWithPhing/logs
```

You should give www-data user the ability to chown. So edit /etc/sudoers and add this line

```
Runas_Alias  APACHE_USERS= www-data
www-data     ALL = (APACHE_USERS): /bin/chmod, /bin/chown
```

Better is to run phing with your developer user and then to this (also in phing task)

```
cd /Users/nomad/Projects/
chown -vR developer:www-data ./
find -type d -exec chmod 775 {} +
find -type f -exec chmod 664 {} +
```